# Tengo problemas para instalar Flask-mysqldb en MAC y Phyton3

Tags: python, python-3.x, ios, flask

soy un principiante en Python y ten problemas para instalar Flask-mysqldb. Flask instaló correctamente  pero no el módulo Flask-mysqldb, he usado el siguiente procedimiento:

`pip3 install flask-mysqldb`

el sistema me arroja el siguiente mensaje:

````
  Using cached 
https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/62/e3/955c845efe1aacf30c8e2607470544ede36aa1044f6382c809f13e014104/Flask-MySQLdb-0.2.0.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: Flask>=0.10 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from flask-mysqldb) (1.1.1)
Collecting mysqlclient (from flask-mysqldb)
  Using cached 
https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f4/f1/3bb6f64ca7a429729413e6556b7ba5976df06019a5245a43d36032f1061e/mysqlclient-1.4.2.post1.tar.gz
    ERROR: Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    ERROR: /bin/sh: mysql_config: command not found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/47/dnqy5tt17zn3m2cbqf_yn5yw0000gn/T/pip-install-bvvt7aee/mysqlclient/setup.py", line 16, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "/private/var/folders/47/dnqy5tt17zn3m2cbqf_yn5yw0000gn/T/pip-install-bvvt7aee/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 51, in get_config
        libs = mysql_config("libs")
      File "/private/var/folders/47/dnqy5tt17zn3m2cbqf_yn5yw0000gn/T/pip-install-bvvt7aee/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 29, in mysql_config
        raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (_mysql_config_path,))
    OSError: mysql_config not found
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/47/dnqy5tt17zn3m2cbqf_yn5yw0000gn/T/pip-install-bvvt7aee/mysqlclient/```


Por favor alguien me puede ayudar?
````

Comment: ¿Tienes instalado `mysql-connector-c` previamente en el sistema? Mirate las instruciones de instalación para mac en https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/

Comment: Estoy intentado pero igual tengo problemas con los permisos